# How to send message with attached image in telegram bot c#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want send message with attached image via telegram bot like this:
[image: Sample liked Result]

My code is here but message is nothing:

```
//var path = "<b>Hello</b>\n"
        //+ "<a href=\"Image\\2.jpg\">&#8203;</a>";
        //+ "<code>and a little bit code</code>\n"
        //string path = System.IO.Path.Combine("Image\\2.jpg");
        string path = @"D:\2.jpg";

        bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "<a href='" + path + "'>My file</a>", ParseMode.Html, false);
```

please resolve this.!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what message does user receive?

Comment: i add 2 inline keyboard bottom of post for selecting or accept

Comment: You said you want to send an image. Is it a file or a URL?

Comment: a file from local storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your message look exactly like on the screenshot in question, you should send a URL of an image in `text` parameter of `SendTextMessageAsync` method (you are now trying to send a file).

However, you can also send your image using `SendPhotoAsync` method. Just specify you text as a `caption` parameter and your file as a stream in `photo` parameter:

```
Message message;
using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FILENAME))
{
    message = await bot.SendPhotoAsync(
        chatId: chatId,
        photo: stream,
        caption: "test photo caption"
    );
}
```

Comment: I know should send a URL of an image in  text  parameter of SendTextMessageAsync method.! 

How to do? by <a href='imagePath' /> or only url without any tag!!??
@Ivan Vinogradov

Comment: You can place URL inside a tag like `Message text with <a href=\"https://telegram.org/img/t_logo.png\">image</a>`, or just place it "as-is" (without <a> tags) in the text message. I can add some examples to answer if you want.

Comment: just what i needed